# How to print a file without being logged in to windows?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printing

I need to print some files programmatically in C#/VB.NET without being needed to be logged in to windows.
Until today I use a solution which needs a form displayed to print, but that doesn't help me with my problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want print without being logged in then you need software that can run when you're not logged in. That would mean a Windows service or else a Console app executed via Task Scheduler. I've only ever done printing in WinForms but I would expect that you could use the same `PrintDocument` class in those types of apps. You should test for yourself and see what happens. Ask a question here if and when you encounter an actual issue.

Comment: As jmcilhinney hinted at, if you are using PrintForm.Print then you need to change it to use PrintDocument and do all the layout in that instead of relying on the on-screen representation.

Comment: Time to be more specific:

As I need to print PDF/TIFF/CAD Files i can't use the PrintDocument Class, right?
I mean the TIFF wouldn't be a problem - I could load the file into a bitmap object, but this doesn't work with PDF and CAD Files i guess? 

Any further suggestions?